# Como tirar while desse exemplo e exibir apenas 1 dado?

Tags: php, mysql

Como tirar while desse exemplo e exibir apenas 1 dado?

```
    $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM dados WHERE id='$id'");
    while($row = $query->fetch_array()){

    echo $row['nome'];
    }
```

Comment: Adicione `LIMIT 1` na sua *query*. Ou use `$row = $query->fetch_array(); echo $row[0]['nome';]`

Comment: $row = $query->fetch_array(); echo $row[0]['nome'];

Comment: usando essa opção ele aparece apenas a primeira letra

Comment: `$row = $query->fetch_array(); echo $row['nome'];`

Comment: Obrigado agora funcionou :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM dados WHERE id='$id'");
    $row = $query->fetch_array();       

    echo $row['nome'];
```